# Fastest and simplest way of getting a list from list in keys of a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary of pattern something like this `{('c1', '#ffe'): (function1, args), ('c2', 'red'): (function2, args), ('c3', ('rbg', 'hex')): (function3, args)}`. 
*(just an example not an actual dictionary but of the same pattern)*

**I want to fetch a list from the first items of tuples that are keys of the dictionary.**

---

I've tried this which works fine but I want to know if there is a simpler or better way.

```py
d = {   
    ('c1', '#ffe'): ('function1', 'args'), 
    ('c2', 'red'): ('function2', 'args'), 
    ('c3', ('rbg', 'hex')): ('function3', 'args')
    }

l = list(dict(list(d)).keys())
print(l)
```

Also, help me make the dictionary more organized with your ideas,

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can skip the part about constructing a dictionary from the keys:

```
l = [k[0] for k in d]
```

In your example, constructing a dictionary from the keys basically does the same, but with the extra work of building up an intermediate dictionary using the "value"-parts of the keys (e.g., `'#ffe'`).

There are two functional differences I can think of:

1. Your dictionary construction will implicitly do a check on the keys of `d`: E.g., if `d` contains a three-part key

   `('c4', 4, 5): ('f4', 'args')`

Then your `dict` construction will raise an exception; while the shorter `k[0]...` iteration would just use `c4` without any error.

2. If `d` contains duplicates in the first part of the key, e.g., an additional `c1`

   `('c1', '#abc'): (...`

Then your `dict` construction will only return one `c1` in the resulting list, whereas the key iteration will yield `c1` twice in the resulting list. Depending on what is desired, that can be used as a sanity check; or you can use

```
l = {k[0] for k in d}
```

to get a set instead of a list.

As for making the dictionary more organized, it depends on what you want to do with it. Structured keys, especially of different forms, as in your example, carry the danger that your "getters" can get rather confusing. In such cases I would explicitly model parts of what you are putting in the dictionary (both keys and values) as classes (e.g., using https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html).

Comment: I believe we can iterate keys with just with `d` like so `[k[0] for k in d]`, but will it make any difference?

Comment: Thanks, I have integrated your comment and expanded on what difference it makes.